# Create websocket with android and spring boot

Tags: android, kubernetes, spring-websocket, docker-desktop

I have create a websocket inside the docker desktop kubernetes spring boot microservice and send text through it to android app.

my class `WebSocketConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

my controller `CartPurchaseCommand.java`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cart-purchase-command")
public class CartPurchaseCommand {
  @MessageMapping("/greetings")
  @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
  public String broadcastNews(@Payload String message) {
    logger.info(">>"+message);
    return message;
  }

}
```

Those are my spring boot classes now let's see my android classes:

`RestModule`:

```
object RestModule{
    fun getWebSocket(): WebSocket {

        val request = Request.Builder().url("ws://my-ip:30000/cart-purchase-command/app/greetings").build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val listener = MyWebSocketListener()

        return client.newWebSocket(request, listener)

    }
}
```

`GpsActivity`:

```
class GpsActivity: ComponentActivity()  {
    private lateinit var webSocket: WebSocketoverride
    private val service=RestModule

    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
          webSocket=service.getWebSocket()
        }

    }

    private fun createLocation() {
        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                for (location in locationResult.locations){
                    // lidar com nulos
                    location?.let {
                        // Envia a localização do usuário para o servidor
                        val json = "{\"latitude\": ${location.latitude}, \"longitude\": ${location.longitude}}"
                        webSocket.send(json)
                        markerPosition.value=LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I get the value sent by android in spring boot?

Comment: check this please: https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you calling `webSocket=service.getWebSocket()` in `setContent`, since it, as any Composable, can be called multiple times. Beside that, the question is not related to Compose, so I'm removing the tag - don't add tags just because some tech is used in your app, only use tags that related to question. Your problem is general for Android, not specific to Compose, which is UI framework

Comment: @gurkan  I'll see later and I'll tell you if I got it

Comment: @gurkan I couldn't make the dependency run in build.gradle do you have a solution? I'm using Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1 jetpack compose project